# Insert Thousands of rows using Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I use Spring JDBC to insert informations that  I read it from a Excel file(xlsx).First, I put the informations in a Vector(size 70 000!!) after that I use  `studentJDBCTemplate.insertListStudents(students)` method from `StudentJDBCTemplate` class  to isert all this Student object to oracle data base.
  My problem is that when I execute this SQL request (`select count(*) from student` ) using Oracle SQL developer, I get only 6041 rows was inserted and no exception was erased in Eclipse console also when I test the size of the Vector, I got 70 000.
  here is My  class:

class Student : Entity

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class Student {
   private Integer age;
   private String name;
   private Integer id;

   public void setAge(Integer age) {
      this.age = age;
   }
   public Integer getAge() {
      return age;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public Integer getId() {
      return id;
   }
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Student [age=");
    builder.append(age);
    builder.append(", name=");
    builder.append(name);
    builder.append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}

}
```

interface StudentDAO : contain all method will be implimented by StudentJDBCTemplate

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public interface StudentDAO {
   /** 
    * This is the method to be used to initialize
    * database resources ie. connection.
    */
   public void setDataSource(DataSource ds);
   /** 
    * This is the method to be used to create
    * a record in the Student table.
    */
   public void create(String name, Integer age);
   /** 
    * This is the method to be used to insert
    * a list of record in the Student table.
    */
   public void insertListStudents(List<Student> listStudent);

}
```

class StudentJDBCTemplate :  contain all CRUD methods

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;    
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchPreparedStatementSetter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class StudentJDBCTemplate implements StudentDAO {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public void create(String name, Integer age) {
        String SQL = "insert into Student (id,name, age) values (SEQ_STUDENT.nextval,?, ?)";

        jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL, name, age);
        System.out.println("Created Record Name = " + name + " Age = " + age);
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void insertListStudents(List<Student> listStudent) {
        String sql = "insert into Student (id,name, age) values (SEQ_STUDENT.nextval,?, ?)";

        jdbcTemplateObject.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                Student student = listStudent.get(i);
                System.out.println("Student "+ i);
                ps.setString(1, student.getName());
                ps.setInt(2, student.getAge());

            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return listStudent.size();
            }

          });
    }
}
```

class ExcelUtil : To read from xls and xlsx files

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelUtil {

    public enum ExtentionFile{
        XLS,XLSX,NONE
    }

    //private Student student = new Student();

    public ExtentionFile checkExcelFile(String pathExcelFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        File file = new File(pathExcelFile);
        if(file.isFile() && file.exists()){

            if(POIXMLDocument.hasOOXMLHeader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathExcelFile)))){
                return ExtentionFile.XLSX;
            }

            if(POIFSFileSystem.hasPOIFSHeader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathExcelFile)))){
                return ExtentionFile.XLS;
            }
        }
        return ExtentionFile.NONE;
    }

    public Vector<Student> readXlsxFile(String pathXlsxFile) throws IOException {
        Vector<Student>students = new Vector<Student>();
        Student student = new Student();
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(pathXlsxFile);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow row;
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
            row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell>cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            student = new Student();
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()){
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                if(null !=cell && (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING ||  cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)){
                    if(!TestISNumber.isNumber(cell.toString())){
                        student.setName(cell.toString());
                    }
                    else if(TestISNumber.isNumber(cell.toString())){
                        student.setAge((int)Double.parseDouble(cell.toString()));
                    }
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(student);
            students.add(student);
        }
        workbook.close();
        return students;    
    }

    public Vector<Student> readXlsFile(String pathXlsFile) throws IOException,InvalidFormatException  {

        Vector<Student> students = new Vector<Student>();
        Student student = new Student();
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(pathXlsFile);
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow row;
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
            row = (HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell>cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            student = new Student();
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()){
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                if(null !=cell && (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING ||  cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)){
                    if(!TestISNumber.isNumber(cell.toString())){
                        student.setName(cell.toString());
                    }
                    else if(TestISNumber.isNumber(cell.toString())){
                        student.setAge((int)Double.parseDouble(cell.toString()));
                    }
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(student);
            students.add(student);
        }
        workbook.close();
        inputStream.close();

        return students;
    }

    public Vector<Student> readFile(String pathFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InvalidFormatException{

        Vector<Student>students = new Vector<Student>();

        if(checkExcelFile(pathFile) == ExtentionFile.XLS){
            students = readXlsFile(pathFile);
        }

        if(checkExcelFile(pathFile) == ExtentionFile.XLSX){
            students = readXlsxFile(pathFile);
        }
        return students;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExcelUtil excelUtil = new ExcelUtil();
        Vector<Student> students = new Vector<Student>();
        try {
            students = excelUtil.readFile("students.xlsx");

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Size of Students Vector: "+students.size());
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(students.toArray()));
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new TreeSet<String>(students).toArray()));

    }

}
```

class TestISNumber : to test if age of student read it from xlsx file can be parsed to double

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestISNumber {

    //Test if Cell contain a String that can be parsed to double 
    public static boolean isNumber (String s){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*^\\d.*)(\\d$)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.matches()){
            return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isNumber("100"));
    }    
}
```

class MainApp: main class

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = 
             new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

      StudentJDBCTemplate studentJDBCTemplate = 
      (StudentJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("studentJDBCTemplate");

      ExcelUtil excelUtil = (ExcelUtil) context.getBean("excelUtilStudent");

      try {
        Vector<Student> students = excelUtil.readXlsxFile("students.xlsx");
        /*for(Student student:students){
            studentJDBCTemplate.create(student.getName(), student.getAge());

        }*/
        studentJDBCTemplate.insertListStudents(students);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
}
```

SQL Script :

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Fichier créé - jeudi-février-26-2015   
--------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Sequence SEQ_STUDENT
--------------------------------------------------------

   CREATE SEQUENCE  "SPRINGJDBC"."SEQ_STUDENT"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 12181 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;

--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table STUDENT
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "SPRINGJDBC"."STUDENT" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "AGE" NUMBER(*,0)
   ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index SYS_C004040
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SPRINGJDBC"."SYS_C004040" ON "SPRINGJDBC"."STUDENT" ("ID");
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table STUDENT
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "SPRINGJDBC"."STUDENT" MODIFY ("ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);

  ALTER TABLE "SPRINGJDBC"."STUDENT" MODIFY ("NAME" NOT NULL ENABLE);

  ALTER TABLE "SPRINGJDBC"."STUDENT" MODIFY ("AGE" NOT NULL ENABLE);

  ALTER TABLE "SPRINGJDBC"."STUDENT" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("ID");
```

XML Bean configuration :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

    <!-- Initialization for data source -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
        <property name="username" value="SPRINGJDBC" />
        <property name="password" value="springjdbc" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Definition for studentJDBCTemplate bean -->
    <bean id="studentJDBCTemplate" class="com.tutorialspoint.StudentJDBCTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Definition for ExcelUtil bean -->
    <bean id="excelUtilStudent" class="com.tutorialspoint.ExcelUtil" />
</beans>
```

PS: 
   I use Spring-3.2.9.Release,Spring-JDBC-3.2.9.Release,ojdbc14,POI-3.11,oracle data base 10g express,Luna Eclipse and JavaSE 1.8 (Oracle JDK)

Comment: If you re-try, is it always 6041 (that would mean the problem is deterministic) or not necessarily?

Comment: @esprittn i would strongly recommend bypassing the application code layer for this type of work and go directly with stored procs. It will enable you to standardise your code, reduce bottlenecks, and substantially improve the performance. Use your application code to grab file name and location and pass to stored proc.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this code in `ExcelUtil`

```
        while(cellIterator.hasNext()){
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            if(null !=cell && (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING ||  cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)){
                if(!TestISNumber.isNumber(cell.toString())){
                    student.setName(cell.toString());
                }
                else if(TestISNumber.isNumber(cell.toString())){
                    student.setAge((int)Double.parseDouble(cell.toString()));
                }
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(student);
        students.add(student);
```

What if, say, this iterator gets to a row with empty cells, or a row containing two cells containing character strings? Either or both properties on the `Student` might remain null, but you add it to the `Vector` anyway. Thus, the size of it will be what you expect (70,000), but that doesn't mean Oracle DB is going to like all of them. Maybe the 6,042nd row has problems. In your debugger, you could add a breakpoint to stop on the addition of a `Student` when it has null fields.

Comment: Agreed. Since both `name` and `age` are `NOT NULL` in the DB, this peace of code may include _null_ students in the vector. It would certainly be good to have rejected rows in a log.

Comment: In my Excel file, there is no empty cell and if age cell contain a string that couldn't be parsed a Exception will be thrown. Also a type of Empty cell is Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK if I write a blank string and null if I don't write any thing on it.